# How to save selected item from drop down list into choice field

Tags: 2013, visual-studio-2012

Actually am fetching data from list to my drop down list(ddlseverity).

I want to get selected value from drop-down and display the value in choice filed in SharePoint list.
after click submit button selected item will not be inserted into choice filed
How can I achieve this?

```
SPFieldChoice fieldChoice = (SPFieldChoice)list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName
                        (itemToAdd.Fields.Add(ddlpriority.Text, SPFieldType.Choice, true));
                        string[] types = { ddlpriority.Text };
                        fieldChoice.Choices.AddRange(types);
                        fieldChoice.Update();
```

Comment: fetching data from list to drop down(ddlseverity) working fine.

Comment: after click submit button selected item  will not be inserted into choice filed

Comment: SPFieldChoice fieldChoice = (SPFieldChoice)list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName
                        (itemToAdd.Fields.Add(ddlpriority.Text, SPFieldType.Choice, true));
                        string[] types = { ddlpriority.Text };
                        fieldChoice.Choices.AddRange(types);
                        fieldChoice.Update();

Comment: You want to create a new Choice column every time or update an existing column

Comment: then you have to update the list also. did you do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29488/discussion-between-atish-dipongkor-and-chakri).

Comment: How to Update choice field from default values to selected item value.

Comment: too many questions in one. add me over skype. skype id: du.atish@outlook.com. see my answer for your last question

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, I got that you wish to create a new column every time. So try something like following

```
 list.Fields.Add("Your Field Name", SPFieldType.Choice, false);
 SPFieldChoice col = (SPFieldChoice) list.Fields["Your Field Name"];

 col.Choices.Add("option 1");
 col.Choices.Add("option 2");
 col.DefaultValue = "option 1"; 

 col.update(); 
 list.update();
```